# Creating Excel Spreadsheet - Library Reference issue

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to create an Excel spreadsheet in C#. I am using VSE 2010.  I added a project reference to

Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library

and my using statements include
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

however, this code gives an error "the type or namespace could not be found" for all the Excel. statements.

Is there anything else I need to be doing?

```
class excelsheet
{
    private static void CreateWorkbook(string FileName)
    {

        Excel.Application xl = null;
        Excel._Workbook wb = null;
        Excel._Worksheet sheet = null;
        //VBIDE.VBComponent module = null;
        bool SaveChanges = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding "using Microsoft.Office.Interop" without the ".Excel"?  Also, is it happening at compile time, or runtime?  Does it compile on any machine? (Perhaps the wrong version of Office is installed where it's failing, for example...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are doing this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Instead, try changing it to a using statement like:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Comment: This worked: using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;  Thanks!